# Use Rexeg to find Specific String and Between Quotes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse strings that look like this.

```
<Report Type="Final Report" SiteName="Get Dataset" Name="Get Metadata" Description="Get Metadata" From="2019-01-16 00:00" Thru="2019-01-16 23:59" obj_device="479999" locations="69,31,">
  <Objective Type="Availability">
    <Goal>99.99</Goal>
    <Actual>100.00</Actual>
    <Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>2880</Checks>
    </Objective>
  <Objective Type="Uptime">
    <Goal/>
    <Actual/>
    <Compliant/>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>0</Checks>
  </Objective>
```

I want to use regex to find the position of 'Description' and then string between the quotes, so I want `'Get Metadata'`.  Then, I want to find the position of 'From' and get the string between the quotes, so I want this `'2019-01-16 00:00'`.  Finally, I want to find the position of 'Thru' and get the string between the quotes, so I want this `'2019-01-16 23:59'`.  How can I do this with 3 separate regex commands and parse this into 3 separate strings?  TIA.

Comment: Looks pretty difficult. How do you feel about using an XML parsing library instead of regex?

Comment: Oh, man, I would love to, but this app has to sit on the Google Cloud, and the cloud doesn't support XML parsing.  I have a very elegant XML solution, which works fine in my client-side setup, but a few of my modules keep failing when I push this into the cloud, simply because it's not supported.

Comment: That's strange. Python has [built-in xml parsing capabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), so it's unusual that Google would specifically exclude standard libraries from its environment. Or could it be that the module _is_ supported, but it's behaving differently compared to your local system? Maybe it's an encoding problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do this with 1 regex pattern

   ```
   pattern = re.compile('Description="(.*)" From="(.*)" Thru="(.*)" obj')

   for founds in re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=string):
       desc, frm, thru = founds
       print(desc)
       print(frm)
       print(thru)

   # ouput
   # Get Metadata
   # 2019-01-16 00:00
   # 2019-01-16 23:59
   ```
2. Or you can do the same step with different patterns

   ```
   pattern_desc = re.compile('Description="(.*)" From')
   pattern_frm = re.compile('From="(.*)" Thru')
   pattern_thru = re.compile('Thru="(.*)" obj')

   re.findall(pattern_desc, string) 
   # output: ['Get Metadata']

   re.findall(pattern_frm, string)
   # output: ['2019-01-16 00:00']

   re.findall(pattern_thru, string)
   # output: ['2019-01-16 23:59']
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should give you the content of description, the others should be similar:

```
'Description="([\w\s]+)" From'
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together a little working example with a regex to get the data you are looking for.

```
import re

long_string = '''
<Report Type="Final Report" SiteName="Get Dataset" Name="Get Metadata" Description="Get Metadata" From="2019-01-16 00:00" Thru="2019-01-16 23:59" obj_device="479999" locations="69,31,">
  <Objective Type="Availability">
    <Goal>99.99</Goal>
    <Actual>100.00</Actual>
    <Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>2880</Checks>
    </Objective>
  <Objective Type="Uptime">
    <Goal/>
    <Actual/>
    <Compliant/>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>0</Checks>
  </Objective>
'''

match = re.search('Description=\"(.+?)\" From=\"(.+?)\" Thru=\"(.+?)\"', long_string)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))
    print(match.group(3))
```

It gives this output:

```
Get Metadata
2019-01-16 00:00
2019-01-16 23:59
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your three regex you need for capturing the mentioned values will be this,

```
Description="([^"]*)"
From="([^"]*)"
Thru="([^"]*)"
```

Which you can generate dynamically through a function and re-use it for finding value for any type of data. Try this python code demo,

```
import re

def getValue(str, key):
 m = re.search(key + '="([^"]*)"',str)
 if m:
  return m.group(1)

s = '''<Report Type="Final Report" SiteName="Get Dataset" Name="Get Metadata" Description="Get Metadata" From="2019-01-16 00:00" Thru="2019-01-16 23:59" obj_device="479999" locations="69,31,">
  <Objective Type="Availability">
    <Goal>99.99</Goal>
    <Actual>100.00</Actual>
    <Compliant>Yes</Compliant>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>2880</Checks>
    </Objective>
  <Objective Type="Uptime">
    <Goal/>
    <Actual/>
    <Compliant/>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Checks>0</Checks>
  </Objective>'''

print('Description: ' + getValue(s,'Description'))
print('From: ' + getValue(s,'From'))
print('Thru: ' + getValue(s,'Thru'))
```

Prints,

```
Description: Get Metadata
From: 2019-01-16 00:00
Thru: 2019-01-16 23:59
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure python, it should be something like this:

```
xml = '<Report Type="Final Report" SiteName="Get Dataset" Name="Get Metadata" Description="Get Metadata" From="2019-01-16 00:00" Thru="2019-01-16 23:59" obj_device="479999" locations="69,31,"><Objective Type="Availability"><Goal>99.99</Goal><Actual>100.00</Actual><Compliant>Yes</Compliant><Errors>0</Errors><Checks>2880</Checks></Objective><Objective Type="Uptime"><Goal/><Actual/><Compliant/><Errors>0</Errors><Checks>0</Checks></Objective>'
report = xml.split('>')[0]
description = report.split("Description=\"")[1].split("\" From=\"")[0]
from_ = report.split("From=\"")[1].split("\" Thru=\"")[0]
thru = report.split("Thru=\"")[1].split("\" obj_device=\"")[0]
```